# Background image is 100% of the screen on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a54o9n8/)

See this [screenshot from my desktop](https://image.prntscr.com/image/6bEa5bn4RFSbTXyZ15rdpw.png)

Now see [this screenshot from my mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PLNq.png)

The image will always cover the whole screen in desktop, at any size of the window.

But in mobile, it is not covering the whole screen,why?

Code

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

CSS:

```
   body  {

    margin: 0px; /* Background Image Margin will be 0 */
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lKW3jvz.jpg'); /*  Background Image Linki */   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* Background Image Will not repeat */
    background-attachment: fixed;  /* Background Image will stay fixed */
    background-size: cover; /* This will make background image width 100% and height 100% */


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a background-image cover the whole screen on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601787/how-to-make-a-background-image-cover-the-whole-screen-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body isn't 100% of window height, so if you add

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then it covers the entire page. Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLjcyqm4/1/)

Comment: @Josh Yes, it was supposed to be `height` but it was `width` by accident

Answer (score 1):

Update following css

```
body, html {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;  /* if not working try vh instead of % */
}
```

```css
body, html {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;  /* if not working try vh instead of % */
}
body  {
 
 margin: 0px; /* Background Image Margin will be 0 */
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lKW3jvz.jpg'); /*  Background Image Linki */   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* Background Image Will not repeat */
    background-attachment: fixed;  /* Background Image will stay fixed */
    background-size: cover; /* This will make background image width 100% and height 100% */
 
 
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

**background-size: cover** makes the background image as large as possible without stretching it, you can read about it here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp):

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

The reason that in mobile your background is not full height is because your body tag has no height.

```css
body  {
    margin: 0px; /* Background Image Margin will be 0 */
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lKW3jvz.jpg'); /*  Background Image Linki */   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* Background Image Will not repeat */
    background-attachment: fixed;  /* Background Image will stay fixed */
    background-size: cover; /* This will make background image width 100% and height 100% */
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9papq9k5/)

Comment: The `height: 100vh;` line is what I was missing. Thanks.